# vmplayer 6 crashes while starting VM

Tags: vmware-player

I installed vmplayer from the binary. However, it always crashes as soon as I want to start a VM.

The log-file states the following errors:

```
2013-12-28T23:08:38.026+01:00| player| I120: CDS error: No install keys defined for fusion-mas
2013-12-28T23:08:41.909+01:00| player| I120: CDS error: Bulletin file /tmp/cdstmp_21676_0 version 3.2.0 is not valid (min: 3.5.0, max: 3.5.0)
```

Comment: Which operating system and version are you using?

Comment: the host system is openSuse 13.1, the guest is Windows 7